# Compare large numbers

Tags: python, compare

For a txt which has the size of files in a dir, I am trying to print the lines where the file appears with less size from a threshold (20Mb) . My code looks like

```
comp = 200000000

with open("files.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       parts = line.split(  ) # split line into parts
       sz=parts[4]
       if ( sz < comp ):
          print parts[4], parts[8]  # print column 2
```

The problem is that although I have a record for instance

```
-rw-rw-r--   2 user zh          22088417  May 28 19:51 test_file.gz
```

the code fails to catch it..I suspect is it some failure from python to compare large numbers ? Any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: you are comparing integers and strings try:`(int(sz) < comp)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe comparing string to integer. Please convert sz into an integer:

```
sz = int(parts[4])
```

Alternatively if you want a float, you would do:

```
sz = float(parts[4])
```